# is_page_template wont allow me to enqueue scripts

Tags: functions, page-template

I want to load specific javascript files onto any page that uses the template `hello-world.php` below is the code that I have used to target the page, register and enqueue scripts. But for some unknown reason it wont enqueue the scripts. Any idea why?

**Functions.php**

```
function my_enqueue_wow() {
  if ( is_page_template( 'hello-world.php' ) ) {
        wp_register_script( 'js-wow', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/wow.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'js-wow', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/wow.min.js');
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_wow' );
```

Comment: Do you have a **proper** [Page Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) called `hello-world.php`?

Comment: I believe is_page and is_page_template are not available inside functions.php

Comment: Is your template in a subdirectory?

Comment: @czerspalace yes it is in a subdirectory.
@s_ha_dum I used a comment like this:  `<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>`

Comment: Try adding the subdirectory name to your template name, like `is_page_template( 'mydirectory/hello-world.php' )` per https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template#Page_template_in_subdirectory